# TCPDF rollbackTransaction on a writeHTMLCell

Tags: php, tcpdf, rollback

I am running in to the following situation with TCPDF:
trying to create a table and cut it off just a the bottom by calculating the Y-value on every `writeHTMLCell`

first the code:

```php
// test the buffer with extra line
$this->pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html_buffer.$row.'</table>', $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=1, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=false); 

if ($this->pdf->getY() < ($this->pdf->getPageHeight() - 100)) { // Note the less-than operator
    // We might be able to add some more text, so undo that
    $this->pdf->rollbackTransaction(true);
    // And store the html
    $html_buffer .= $row;
}else{
    // We exceeded our limit
    $this->pdf->rollbackTransaction(true);
    // Write last known good table
    $this->pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html_buffer.'</table>', $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=false);
    // Add a new page
    $this->pdf->AddPage();
    // End this transaction
    $this->pdf->commitTransaction();
    // Start a new transaction
    $this->pdf->startTransaction();
    // Reset html buffer
    $html_buffer = '<table>';
    // Add line we couldn't fit on last page to html buffer
    $html_buffer .= $row;
}
```

(got this from [TCPDF split html table on multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221174/tcpdf-split-html-table-on-multiple-pages))

But the output-pdf is showing the results of the first `writeHTMLCell` too, which is only used for testing the Y-value. 
It seems the rollback is not working?

output goes like:

```
row 1
row 1
row 2
row 1
row 2
row 3
row 1
row 2
row 3
row 4
```

any clues on where it goes wrong?